# Jquery não funciona no Browser do Celular

Tags: jquery, mobile, navegador-de-internet

Eu tenho uma página responsiva pra fazer um e-commerce e tenho o seguinte código para adicionar ou remover quantidade:

```
// HTML
<a class="menos" class='fas fa-minus-circle'><i></i></a>
<p class="qtde">0</p>
<a class="mais" class='fas fa-minus-circle'><i></i></a>

// jQuery (estou usando o jQuery comum e não o jQuery mobile):
$(document).on('click', '.menos', function() {
    // Retira quantidade
});

$(document).on('click', '.mais', function() {
    // Soma quantidade
});
```

No PC e em celulares android funcionou.
No iPhone não funcionou nem no Safari e nem no Chrome.

Em outros posts aqui no fórum sugeriram adicionar ao click a função touchstart e também usar mousedown no lugar do click e ficou assim:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.mais', function() {
    // Soma quantidade
});
// ou
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', '.mais', function() {
    // Soma quantidade
});
```

No PC normal.

No Android ele executou a função duas vezes seguidas (0-2-4 ...).

No iPhone aí que está, funcionou num iPhone X tanto no Safari quanto no Chrome mas não funcionou num iPhone 7 Plus tanto no Safari quanto no Chrome, todos os dispositivos estão atualizados e com os apps na mesma versão.

Como posso proceder?

Comment: Use `button` no lugar de `a`. A tag `a` é usada para navegação e não para alterar elementos.

Comment: Ola @Sam, realmente funcionou também! Precisei só modificar o CSS mas resolveu também! 
Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente vai ter que usar o jQuery Mobile.
Para que a execução não se repita, adicione um `preventDefault()` e `stopPropagation()`

```js
$(document).on('click touchstart', '.mais', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Uma alternativa é usar Javascript mesmo:

```html
<div class="menos" ontouchstart="touchStart(menos);"><i class='fas fa-minus-circle'></i></div>
<p class="qtde">0</p>
<div class="mais" ontouchstart="touchStart(mais);"><i class='fas fa-minus-circle'></i></div>
```

```js
element.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStart, false);
```

```js
function touchStart(event) {
  // executa o evento
}
```

Comment: Douglas, muito obrigado pela sua colaboração! Eu não conhecia a atuação do preventDefault() e do stopPropagation(). 

Realmente com javascript puro foi possível fazer também!!!! Eu nunca trabalhei o JQuery Mobile, eu tenho que fazer alguma verificação se o site está no navegador do PC ou do Celular???????? Porque estou usando Bootstrap para cuidar da parte de ser responsivo.

Comment: Não precisa, basta inserir no código a chamada do jQuery Mobile e ele vai atuar sozinho quando tiver que executar